# How can I throttle CPU usage for a website in IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have an asp.net MVC web app that processes images and resizes them which is working great besides that fact that it often hogs all of my server resources.  How can it throttle this web app to consume very little cpu?  All it does is process images so I do not care about how responsive it is because it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Should this be on ServerFault instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setup AppPool  of your website/service. Here is some [inforamtion](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/449/using-wsrm-to-manage-iis-7-apppool-cpu-utilization/).

Comment: I have an AppPool setup but it really doesn't tell me how to limit my usage to say 20%.  Looks like I have 2 options, ignore and kill.  Killing it is not really throttling as far as I am concerned, I want to finish what I am doing just not hog all resources.

Comment: @Slee I don't understand. If you look at the link, inside it you can find: AppPool -> Advancet settings -> CPU -> Limit. Here you can setup all what you want.

Comment: @Slee You think Limit action ?

Comment: A little heads up for those reading this answer in 2016 and later ;) The link points to instructions about using WSRM which as of Windows Server 2015 is depreciated. In Windows Server 2012 / IIS 8.0, the throttling is configured in the advanced options of the App Pool.